# Game Art? Should Questions go here or in a new wiki?

Tags: discussion, migration, community-wiki

Seems like a lot of people may have questions about game art, especially 3D programming techniques. A lot of people like myself are self-taught and continually trying to pick up tricks that art-school types may have received via formal course-work.

What's the appropriate venue for art-related questions?  Should there be a new "Game Art" or simply "Artists" wiki for such questions, or is Game Development the proper place?

Comment: If I recall correctly, there has been an attempt at a graphics (or 3D graphics?) oriented Stack Exchange site, it didn't make it out of beta.

Comment: Interesting, not surprising though... `Game Development` itself seems pretty low-use.  I asked one XNA-centric question and received no replies for weeks, where I've seen similar questions answered quickly on `App Hub`.  My new approach is to post on both sites, assuming the `App Hub` one is most likely to "hit" a good response.

Comment: Ah found it, it's still in public beta: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ and there is a suggestion for a SE for creating art: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7250/art-creation

Comment: Cool thanks, you should post that as an answer so I can give you full credit. :)  Tetrad's answer I feel is less complete than yours.

Answer (score 3):

*Specific* art questions are on topic for this site.  I don't have any examples offhand of good art-centric questions, though.

Comment: There was [one](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12397/how-to-depict-a-ramp-for-a-top-down-2d-perspective) that was *somewhat* specific, but it was closed as they had asked the same question at the [graphic design beta](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/), which seems like a good place to direct those types of questions in my opinion.

Comment: So would the correct answer be http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ then??

Comment: no, unless it's a graphic design question. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq  3D art is off topic there.  2D art might be.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Graphics Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange currently in beta.

Additionally there is a [proposed site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7250/art-creation) that seems to fit the desires you have, covering art creation in general. From the proposal:

> **Art Creation**
>
> Proposed Q&A site for artists, painters, drawers, caricaturists,
> illustrators, cartoonists, graphic artists, engravers, sculptors, etc.
> Basically art techniques and methodologies.

However, I don't know how long these things generally take, but the Art Creation site was proposed nearly a year ago and only has 10% commitment. Seems a long way off from the 100% needed to start beta. I guess it's time to start some promotion of your own if you want to get the site off the ground :)

As far as where the questions should go. I agree with Tetrad that on topic questions should come to us, I just don't think they have the same chance of being answered. Personally, if I had an art question, I would go for the site that's more likely to get the question answered, Graphics Design.